# Efficiency check for sorting data table

Tags: powershell

This is a reasonably generic question, but I'm wondering if some PS gurus can advise on whether my method for sorting and recombining some data fields by using an array of PSCustomObjects is as efficient as it might be.

I'm importing a CSV file that contains a number of person details, including Full Names in a single field that have a variety of separators between first and last names (e.g. comma, space, comma + space, semicolon, etc). Last name comes first. Sanitising those variants is also an objective.

The dataset needs to be sorted by last name and reassembled with a single FullName field. Doing a simple sort by the FullName field doesn't work reliably given the variety of delimiters between the name parts.

I've attempted it creating an array of new PSCustomObjects that comprises of all the original fields from the CSV plus the Full Name field split into two new name fields. It's then sorted by the last name, and the results are stored in a new array ready for output, joining the previously-split name fields back together with a comma and space.

Any suggestions for better efficiency welcome.

```
$data = import-csv .\Cust.csv
# CSV fields: FullName, StreetAddress, City, Postcode
# Create a temporary array for sorting
$splitNames = @()
$data | foreach {
    $spltName = $_.FullName -split '[\s|,|;]+'
    $splitNames += [PSCustomObject]@{
        Last = $spltName[0]
        First = $spltName[1]
        StreetAddress = $_.StreetAddress
        City = $_.City
        Postcode = $_.Postcode
    }
}
# Create an output array to hold the final result
$sortedNames = @()
# Sort the temporary array by lastname, rejoin name field and add to output array
$splitNames | Sort Last | foreach {
    $FullName = $_.Last, $_.First -join ', '
    $sortednames += [PSCustomObject]@{
        FullName = $Fullname
        StreetAddress = $_.StreetAddress
        City = $_.City
        Postcode = $_.Postcode
    }
}
$sortednames
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for a code review rather than about a technical issue with the code. Consider posting it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I didn't realise there was such a sub-site.